# In a site-to-site VPN, can a computer on site A use the gateway on site B?

Tags: vpn, ubiquiti

I'm running a site-to-site VPN set up with 2 Ubiquity Edgemax routers. Hosts on both sites can see each other, etc. I'm looking for a way to set up site B in a way that all of its hosts use site A as their gateway.

In other words, I want all (or optionally, some) hosts in site B to reach the internet via site A's ISP.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Can't you just set a static default route to point to the tunnel? You may need a specific static route for the other router that points to the ISP. That way, any traffic destined for unknown destinations will cross the tunnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, I want all (or optionally, some) hosts in site B to reach the internet via site A's ISP.
>
> How would I approach this?

Normally, we build up a VPN tunnel between two sites so that they could privately and securely reach each other. In this case, the Encryption Domains (local and remote subnets) are limited to the subnets we have at each site.

Now, we want internet traffic for Site-B to pass through Site-A (Site-B_internet traffic runs over the VPN tunnel between Site-A and Site-B), you would need to modify the Encryptions Domains at both ends to cover all Internet hosts/IPs - `0.0.0.0/0` or `any`. 
At this time, when Site-B wants to access the Internet, traffic is encrypted and sent over the VPN tunnel to Site-A. At Site-A this "Internet traffic" is decrypted and forwarded out to the Internet.

I wrote an answer for a similar question in our Networking SE site but on Cisco devices at [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45125/cisco-asa-site-to-site-vpn-remote-lans-have-no-internet/45166#45166). I hope it would give you more ideas.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is indeed a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: @SuitedSloth You are welcome! And as you do not have any further concern, please accept my answer as the solution.